# How to prevent recursive activation of form submit button when trying to activate once using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, django, click

I am creating a Django app that retrieves data from a database based on a form. The form is just a collection of checklists. The data is then used to create a plot using Bokeh.

The app works. That is, when the submit button is pressed, the app accepts user input, collects relevant data and plots a graph. My problem is that I want to form to be submitted once as soon as the page loads, in order to display a graph with the default settings. The current behaviour is that no graph is displayed until the user presses the submit button.

Here is an abstract example that *kind of* reproduces my problem. Please note that my problem isn't exactly reproduced by this example because my inexperience with html/javascript makes it difficult to make html/javascript equivalent of what Django is doing. However, here's an attempt. Just bear in mind that a graph should be dynamically produced when the button is pressed - which graph is shown depends on user input.

```html
<div id='form-container'>
  <form action='.' name='ctrl-panel' method='post' class='form-check-inline'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label id="label1">
        <input id='label1' type='checkbox' name='checkbox1' value='A' checked='checked'>Checkbox 1
      </label>
      </li>

      <li>
        <label id="label2">
        <input id='label2' type='checkbox' name='checkbox2' value='A'>Checkbox 2
      </label>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </form>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn" id="submit-btn" form="ctrl-panel">

</div>

<script>
  window.onload = function clickBtnOnWindowLoad() {
    var btn = document.getElementById('submit-btn');
    btn.click();
  }
</script>
```

The issue is that the `action` on the form is set to the current page `.` and the javascript code runs when the page is loaded. Therefore, I am getting a recursive activation of the submit button, since the submit button loads the current page and loading the current page pressed the submit button.

Does anybody have any advice so that I can submit the form once, and only once, with default settings when the page loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm far away from Django, but logically there are two ways to solve this problem:

1. From the backend detect, whether the page loaded first time (without any data requested) or not. If yes - render form with the script, else don't render the form;
2. Change `POST` to `GET` so all submitted values will be appended to the query string to the URL. Then, if there is any query in URL (that can be detected with `location.search`, do not run the script:

(something like this)

```
<script>
    window.onload = function clickBtnOnWindowLoad() {
        var btn = document.getElementById('submit-btn');
        if (!location.search)
            btn.click()
    }
</script>
```

But generally, if you wish always to render the form in case of user's input dependable data, your approach to do this is not so good. I suppose, you should consider to use AJAX request.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use window onload because the function will run when the page is loaded.

if you still would like to keep it this way you could do an if statement like this:

```
var x = 0:  
If x == 0  //when page is loaded
  DO NOTHING  
  x = x + 1
else if x > 0  //because the page is loaded and x is now 1
  DO THE CODE WHEN CLICKING BUTTON
```

> *Disclaimer* currently programming in python and its been a while since i used 
>     javascript so formatting may not be optimal, this is just an example